# Android onTouch irregular shape

Tags: java, android

How can I check in an `onTouchEvent` if you touch a irregular shape like [this isometric one](http://www.clker.com/clipart-25280.html)?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you have your shape drawn onto the screen already? If so how did you do that?

Comment: As a Bitmap on a surfaceView.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Drawing a shape and performing hit tests against it are 2 very different things.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Yes, but if it's a bitmap with transparent non-hit areas, that makes it very simple if you know where you're drawing it.

Comment: @Geobits If you're performing no rotation, scaling, skewing, or translation that's a good solution. Translation is trivial to fix actually. The rest not as easy. Might work great for Stupe though, good comment.

Answer (score 1):

Check if coordinates from `MotionEvent` are inside your shape:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    final float x = event.getX();
    final float y = event.getY();
    if (isInside(x, y))
    {
         // do something
    }
    return true;
}

boolean isInside(float x, float y)
{
    // TODO: return true, if (x,y) is inside your shape, otherwise return false
}
```

Comment: You  have to learn how a click happened in a shape. For complex shape, laser projection exists. Take a look at your prefered search engine ;)

Comment: The points are being sampled, meaning if the user swipes quickly you won't be able to tell he ever touched the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `MotionEvent` coordinates are inside your shape, then do a point-in-polygon hit test.

If your isometric shape is a diamond with equal length segments, **and** has angles of all 90 degrees (as corrected by Geobits in comments), a quick test can be done using [Manhatten Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). Check out the link, the pictures make it more clear why this works.

```
int rectSize = 10;
Rectangle diamondBoundingRect = new Rectangle(0,0,rectSize,rectSize);
Point point = new Point(9,9);
int dx = Math.abs(point.x - diamondBoundingRect.center.x);
int dy = Math.abs(point.y - diamondBoundingRect.center.y);
if(dx+dy < rectSize){
    //point is inside diamond
}else{
    //point is not inside diamond
}
```

This test is inflexible, but it may be all you need.

If you need something better, [this blog post](http://www.ytechie.com/2009/08/determine-if-a-point-is-contained-within-a-polygon.html) explains the algorithm for point-in-polygon hit tests.

The idea is to cast a line (called a Ray) from your `MotionEvent` point to your polygon, and count the number of intersections between that line and line segments in that polygon. If the count is even, the point is outside the shape. If its odd, the point is inside the shape.

[Wikipedia has a nice picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) and more details to help you understand the logic in this approach.

*Concentrate on getting that to work before this next part as it may prove unnecessary depending on your needs.*

The points sent to you in your `onTouchEvent` are sampled. The device is just giving you points and direction at some predetermined rate. The faster the user moves his finger, the less detail you have as the sampling rate can't keep up.

So, if you want more detail, you'll have to [interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) . This is an advanced way of saying you need to guess where the user swiped his fingers with some fancy math. Cosine interpolation has worked well for me in the past as its a good balance between speed and results.

Edit:

Here's some code I use personally for point-in-polygon hit tests.

```
public boolean isPointInsidePolygon(double x, double y){
    //pointAry holds the polygon's vertices.
    int polySides = this.pointAry.Length;
    //need at lest 3 vertices to create a polygon.
    if (polySides < 3)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int j = polySides - 1;
    boolean oddNodes = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < polySides; i++)
    {
        Point pi = this.pointAry[i];
        Point pj = this.pointAry[j];
        if (pi.y < y && pj.y >= y || pj.y < y && pi.y >= y)
        {
            if (pi.x + (y - pi.y) / (pj.y - pi.y) * (pj.x - pi.x) < x)
           {
                oddNodes = !oddNodes;
            }
        }
        j = i;
     }
     return oddNodes;
 }
```

Comment: Just the width or height of the rectangle. I've edited the answer. A diamond with all equal length sides will have a bounding rectangle with all equal length sides. Size was the length of any one of the bounding rectangle's sides. `rectSize` in that example is 10.

Comment: Okay now I see that my Shape has not equal length segments. My Rectangle is 46*24px. Do you have any clear idea how to handle the touch with such a size?

Comment: Manhattan distance doesn't work for all diamonds of equal length segments. Technically, it only works if all the angles are 90 degrees as well(making the bounding box a square). The OP's diamond is a perfect case in point, since the side lengths are all the same.

Comment: @Stupe implement the even-odd-rule algorithm I linked and talked about in the second half my question. That will work with your polygon.

Comment: @Geobits ah shoot, you're right. Thanks, I'll edit my answer and credit you.

Comment: @Stupe added code to do point in polygon hit tests. I use this code at work in C#. converted to java for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to write some code that detect if a given point (x, y) is in your irregular shape.

```
public boolean isInIrregularShape(int x, int y);
```

You'll have to define the shape in some way. You might want to search on Google for some libraries that let you define a shape and check if a given point is inside of the shape. Your x and y points would be `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're drawing your shape as a Bitmap on a SurfaceView, you can just test the transparency of the pixel you touched. The Bitmap's pixel, that is, not the SurfaceView's.

For example, with a bitmap drawn at 100,150(surfaceview coords for left/top):

```
float x = getX() - 100;
float y = getY() - 150;
int alpha = Color.alpha(myBitmap.getPixel(x, y));
if(alpha == 0)
    // not hit!
else
    // hit!
```

Note: This doesn't take scaling into effect, so you'll have to know the scale factor and multiply accordingly if you're drawing them scaled.

Comment: This also doesn't take skew or rotation into consideration.

Comment: True, it's really just a base implementation. You should also check the bounding box first. Better answers can be found searching the `algorithm` tab.